# Wrap multiple lines in one div

Tags: ckeditor

Currently in CKeditor, the style drop-down let you wrap content with block or inline tags.

If you select multiples lines in the editor and chose a div element in the style menu, each lines will be wrapped individually in a div element.

Is it possible to select multiple lines and then wrap them in one div?

Comment: Have you tried [that](http://ckeditor.com/addon/div) plugin?

Comment: Yes, I have seen this one, it's working, but sadly it add more steps and from the user perspective it looks redundant and not very intuitive compared to the style dropdown.